# Why $[0,1]\times (0,1)$ and $[0,1)\times (0,1)$ are not homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology

This question has been asked here [Homeomorphisms in $\mathbb{R}^2$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1208768/homeomorphisms-in-mathbbr2?rq=1), but I don't understand in the answer said that they are not homeomorphic since boundary of $[0,1]\times (0,1)$ has two connected components, while $[0,1)\times (0,1)$ only has one.

I'm confused about the "boundary" in that answer, aren't boundaries of $[0,1]\times (0,1)$ and $[0,1)\times (0,1)$ same in $\Bbb{R}^2$? And why this shows the two subspaces are not homeomorphic? Thanks!

Comment: Read the answer you’re referring to more carefully. The two sets you’re looking at are not the ones that are proved to be non homeomorphic

Comment: @marwalix typed wrong, edited

Comment: Where must a homeomorphism send a connected boundary component?

Comment: @EricTowers I'm confused about the "boundary" in that answer, aren't $[0,1]\times (0,1)$ and $[0,1)\times (0,1)$ have same boundary in $R^2$?

Comment: He is not talking about the topological boundary, but the boundary as a manifold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A_1 = [0,1] \times (0,1)$ and $A_2 = [0,1)\times(0,1)$.

We have $$\partial A_1 = \partial A_2 = [0,1]^2 \setminus (0,1)^2$$

and hence

$$A_1 \cap \partial A_1 = \{0,1\} \times (0,1)$$

$$A_2 \cap \partial A_2 = \{0\} \times (0,1)$$

If $f : A_2 \to A_1$ is a homeomorphism, we have $f(\partial A_2) = \partial A_1$ (why?) so
$$f(A_2 \cap \partial A_2) = f(A_2) \cap f(\partial A_2) = A_1 \cap \partial A_1$$

Since $A_2 \cap \partial A_2$ is a connected set and $f$ is continuous, it follows that $A_1 \cap \partial A_1$ is a connected set as well. This is a contradiction.