# Is the closed strip homeomorphic to the closed half-plane?

Tags: general-topology

Let
$$
X = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: 0 \le x \le 1\}
\quad 
Y = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: 0 \le x\}.
$$

Are $X$ and $Y$ homeomorphic?

I first thought no because their boundaries
are not homeomorphic however the argument is flawed
because the theorem I want to use is:

If $X \cong Y$ then for $A \subseteq X$
$$
\partial_X (A) \cong \partial_Y(f(A)).
$$
So applying this theorem would yield
$$
\partial_X(X) \cong
\partial_Y(Y)
\implies \emptyset \cong \emptyset
$$
which is not helpful. Any hints?

Comment: Try looking at $X\setminus\mathrm{interior}(X)$ and $Y\setminus\mathrm{interior}(Y)$. Any homeomorphism should also be a homeomorphism on these sets, but these sets are not the same (One is path-connected, the other is not)

Comment: @student91 Again, $\operatorname{int}_X(X) = X$ because every set is open in itself. It's the same problem with the boundary case. Yo do *not* have an homeomorfism from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to itself.

Comment: @student91: What do you mean by "interior(X)"? The (topological) interior of $X$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$? Or of $X$ itself? Or, as assumed in the answer of jfab, $X \setminus \delta X$, where $\delta X$ is the boundary of $X$ in the sense of algebraic topology? Please note that only the last option provides a valid proof. However, the background to this option is not as trivial as for the first two options. But perhaps you had this in mind, and my comment is irrelevant?

Comment: Yes maybe my comment is a bit stupid. I was in the back of my head thinking of "interior" and "boundary" in terms of how one would do for manifolds with boundary, so "interior" point = one which has a nbh isomorphic to open disc, "boundary" point = one which has a nbh isomorphic to half-disc, but I guess this does not work here.

Comment: hmmm I guess it does work after all, $\mathrm{Int}(X):=\{x\in X\colon\exists f\colon D^2\to X,\ f^{-1}(x)\neq\varnothing\}$ is a very sensible definition of interior that does help with this question.

Comment: Yes, sure, this will work. I just wanted to emphasise that it's not just considering interiors in the sense of a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$. And, hence, you need, at least a little bit, some machinery of algebraic topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To proof it without using any algebraic topology, the same as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4311465/is-there-a-neat-way-to-prove-that-r2-is-not-homeomorphic-to-r2-0-0/4313330#4313330) works:

Call a space $X$ *compactly connected*, if
for each compact subset $A$ of $X$ there is compact subset $B$ of $X$, such that $A \subseteq B$ and $X \setminus B$ is connected.

$Y = [0,\infty) \times \mathbb{R}$ is compactly connected, since each compact subset is contained in a compact rectangle, such that one of its edges lies on the $y$-axis. The remainder consists of three (infinite, non-closed) "rectangles", where one intersects the other two. Hence it is connected.

$X = [0,1] \times \mathbb{R}$ is not compactly connected:
Let $A := [0,1] \times \{0\}$. Then for any compact $B$ with $A \subset B$, $X \setminus B$ is not connected.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$
X = [0,1] \times \mathbb{R} \cong [0,1] \times (0,1)
\quad 
Y = [0,\infty) \times \mathbb{R} \cong [0,1) \times
(0,1)
$$
it suffices to show that the latter are not
homeomorphic and this has been asked in
[Homeomorphisms in $\mathbb{R}^2$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1208768/homeomorphisms-in-mathbbr2?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I believe the accepted answer is incorrect because of the
same reason I mentioned, taking boundaries in $\mathbb{R}^2$
rather than on $X$ and on $Y$, however the comment to
that answer appears to be correct (defining the "boundary" as the set of points so that $X \setminus \{p\}$ is simply connected).